# How to turn Int/String Array into a binary tree with Nodes?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

In Java, write a method called tree builder using the node class provided

tree builder is a method takes an int array of input and builds a tree in pre-order 
TA Notes: Apologies there should also be a post and in order traversal for this
tree

build from these arrays

pre order [19 47 23 -2 55 63 94 28]

in order [23 47 55 -2 19 63 94 28]
post order [23 55 -2 47 28 94 63 19]
this tree

```
            | 19 |
            +----+
           /      \
          /        \
      +----+      +----+
      | 47 |      | 63 |
      +----+      +----+
     /      \           \
    /        \           \
+----+      +----+      +----+
| 23 |      | -2 |      | 94 |
+----+      +----+      +----+
           /                  \
          /                    \
      +----+                  +----+
      | 55 |                  | 28 
public class TreeNode {
    public int data;       // data stored at this node
    public TreeNode left;  // reference to left subtree
    public TreeNode right; // reference to right subtree

    // post: constructs a leaf node with given data
    public TreeNode(int data) {
        this(data, null, null);
    }

    // post: constructs a node with the given data and links
    public TreeNode(int data, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

public class Tree {
    private TreeNode root;

    public void treeBuilder(int[] array,int[] array) {
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
     // this is where I initalize a node but I'm not sure
     // how to build in pre-order
   }

   }
}
```

I know how to print a tree in pre-order traversal that's just basic recursion 
but I'm not sure how to move from having a int array to having a tree node

Comment: And the root is the first node in the tree / first element of the array. Typically, every 2N and 2N+1 elements are the children of array index N

Comment: sorry it's a method, should have clarified

Comment: Are you given an example array and expected tree?

Comment: yep just posted it

Comment: Well, since pre-order starts at the root, then left, you can at least get 19, and 47, but I think it requires more information to know when you stop adding to the left node

Comment: Actually, is that really the tree you need to build? 47, 23, 55 should all be to the right of 19?

Comment: There is no logic behind building such a tree. Multiple tree types can yield the same preorder.

Comment: As I understand the problem, you want to build a tree such that when you traverse the tree in pre-order you get the posted array.  There are many such trees that can be constructed to do that.  The easiest, which was already mentioned (implied). is to just have a linked list of all right nodes starting with 19.

Comment: do the post and in order traversal helps ill ask my TA

Comment: `do the [post- and in-order traversals help` With unique values, one way to specify a binary tree serially and unambiguously is to give the in-order traversal and either the pre-order or the post-order one. Check your "ASCII-art" tree: does the in-order traversal match `[23 55 -2 47 28 94 63 19]`? (Or, do the labels `post order` and `in order` match the arrays and the tree?)

Comment: yes they all do

Comment: @greybeard yes I did my post and in order are switched around will fix that

Answer (score 0):

**How to get a `TreeNode` from an `int[]`** or two

The value of the root node appears right at the start of the pre-order sequence, to be followed by all values in the sub-trees, each contiguous.

1) Take one value from the pre-order sequence
find it in the in-order sequence:
  all values in the left subtree will appear before, so you know their count
  all values in the right subtree will appear after
recursively construct the 2) left and 3) right sub-tree
instantiate a `TreeNode` using 1), 2) and 3).

Answer (score 0):

Edited my answer as I did not understand the question correctly.

He wants to build the tree given the three traversal results.

The solution is given here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-a-binary-tree-from-postorder-and-inorder/

Comment: @grey help me out.